# Can users manually change authenticated Axios requests?

Tags: php, reactjs, authentication, axios, jwt

Is it possible for an end user to manually change the contents of an Axios request (in React), e.g. with developer tools, when my back-end requires an authentication token with each request?

If yes, is there a way to prevent this? I want to make sure all data sent to the php back-end results from real user-interactions on my website.

Comment: People can use Postman tool to replicate request data and send requests.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Yes anyone (person or bot) can craft a request any way they want to, but unless they know the value of a valid token, it's kind of pointless for them to do that and valid tokens presumably only come after valid interactions with the server.

Comment: @apokryfos could they obtain the token from a previous valid request, then alter a next one?

Comment: Your token is valid for however long you want it to be. If you believe people will hijack tokens, you might want to shorten the window and prompt for authentication more often, and/or you can bind the token to additional user data such as IP or UA. If talking JWT specifically, make sure to “pin” the algorithm server-side, don’t blindly trust the alg, and make sure to sign and _verify_ the token.

Comment: If you are using a bearer token (which is typical for JWTs) then someone just having it is proof enough that they got it from a legitimate interaction with the website (at some point in time). Users can typically reuse their older tokens, that should be allowed, and you can control how long your tokens are valid for. If the concern is someone getting the token from someone else this is a fundamental problem in cybersecurity and there's no generic answer. There will be mitigation strategies but these need to be tailored to your specific site by someone who understands the theory and your site

Comment: @ everyone above. all helpful advice thankyou